# How to customize ".NET 8 Identity" routes - MapIdentityApi

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, .net-8.0

I added the new identity endpoint from .NET 8 with .MapIdentityApi().
How can I expand the "/register" and "/login" endpoint to allow the username to be passed? When I register a user the username is set as the email.

I expanded the IdentityUser with additional fields and migrated the classes to my MySQL database. That worked fine. All the endpoints stayed the same.

Comment: Customising Identity endpoints has been requested here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/50303.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I did.
I took the source code @
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityApiEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.cs

I copied that and put it in my .NET 8 Api Application.
Then I changed the line:

```
 public static IEndpointConventionBuilder MapIdentityApi<TUser>(this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
```

to

```
public static IEndpointConventionBuilder MapCustomIdentityApi<TUser>(this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
```

There are a couple of references to the class name in the code that you'll need to update. Based on what end points you keep. I removed the register, which is one, the other is the confirm email.

Then I added/removed/customized the endpoints in there.

Then in Program.cs I called:

```
app.MapCustomIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();
```

Hopefully, you can take it from there and save the world!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the user name entered from user, then @Code-Sharpening's answer is a good idea.

If you want to change the route, then use

```
            app.MapGroup("/api")
                .MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();
```

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a better way... but a quick short hack following up on @user1579943's comments with a bit of additional detail.

Subclass your custom user from IdentityUser

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string? Name { get; set; } = "";
    public string? Street { get; set; } = "";
    public string? City { get; set; } = "";
    public string? State { get; set; } = "";
    public string? Zip { get; set; } = "";
    public string? Phone { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Create a matching Dto

```
public record CreateUserDto(
    string Email,
    string Password,
    string Name,
    string Street,
    string City,
    string State,
    string Zip,
    [Required]
    string Phone,
);
```

Hack the IdentityApiEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions to match.

```
public static class IdentityApiEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions
{
    private static readonly EmailAddressAttribute _emailAddressAttribute = new();

    public static IEndpointConventionBuilder MapCustomIdentityApi<TUser>(this IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
        where TUser : MyUser, new()
    {

        .....

        routeGroup.MapPost("/register", async Task<Results<Ok, ValidationProblem>>
            ([FromBody] CreateUserDto registration, HttpContext context, [FromServices] IServiceProvider sp) =>
        {

            .....

            var user = new TUser
            {
                Name = registration.Name,
                Street = registration.Street,
                City = registration.City,
                State = registration.State,
                Zip = registration.Zip,
                Phone = registration.Phone,
            };

        }

    }

    ....
}
```